# "jQuery rotate" plugin .Rotate and save the image to a file

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using "jQuery rotate" plugin to rotate my image with this code (when I click the button) :

```
$.post(urlToPHP, {rotation:rotation}, function(data) { 
  var rotation = 0; 
  $("#left").click(function() {
    rotation = (rotation -90) % 360; // the mod 360 probably isn't needed
    $("#spin-pic").rotate(rotation);
  }); 
  $("#right").click(function() {
    rotation = (rotation + 90) % 360; // the mod 360 probably isn't needed
    $("#spin-pic").rotate(rotation);
  }); 
});
```

I have tried to save the rotated image using php below, but it was unsuccessful:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 

$src = $_SESSION['picture'];



if($_SESSION['format'] == "image/png")
{
   $img_r =  imagecreatefrompng($src); 
} 
if($_SESSION['format'] == "image/gif")
{
   $img_r =  imagecreatefromgif($src); 
} 

 if($_SESSION['format'] == "image/jpeg")
  {
   $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src); 
}

  $img_r = imagerotate($img_r, $_POST['rotation'], 0);


    if($_SESSION['format'] == "image/png")
  {
imagepng($img_r, 'upload/' . basename($src));
} 
 if($_SESSION['format'] == "image/gif")
  {
imagegif($img_r, 'upload/' . basename($src));
} 
  if($_SESSION['format'] == "image/jpeg")
  {
imagejpeg($img_r, 'upload/' . basename($src)); //send file to "upload" and overwrites the old picture...
} 



                      **THANK YOU SEAN!!!** 


?>
```

Please have a look at the code and correct me. Thanks a lot:)

Comment: You assign to `$img_r` then try to do something  with `$dst_r`. Was that intended?

Comment: What links the client-side effect to the sever-side script?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my code . Please have a look

Comment: That makes slighlt more sense though it could be simplified and it's still not clear how the clint-side code and the server-side code relate to each other. Is some kind of form submission of AJAX request involved?

Comment: When you want to save the img, the easiest would be to post the `rotation` to your php code, ie. `$.post(urlToPHP, {rotation:rotation}, function(data) { });`. Then in your php you can use the value with [`imagerotate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php) -> `$img_r = imagerotate($img_r, $_POST['rotation'], 0);`

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks, I have updated my question, can you have a look and correct me?

Comment: @Sean . Please have a look at my updated code and tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: No that is not correct. Just to clarify, do you want to post to your php page, similar to a form which would reload the page, or do you want to do this with ajax so you stay on the same page without page reload.

Comment: @Sean . Yes, I want to post on my php page

Comment: I will post an idea as an answer

Comment: Sorry, it took me a few minutes as I had to do something for my son. I have now posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st, you need to add a 'save' button (similar to your `#left`/`#right`), that when clicked will post the `rotation` to your php code.

```
$(function() {                                 
    var rotation = 0;                            
    $("#left").click(function() {
        rotation = (rotation -90) % 360; 
        $("#spin-pic").rotate(rotation);
    });
    $("#right").click(function() {
        rotation = (rotation + 90) % 360;
        $("#spin-pic").rotate(rotation);
    });
    $("#save").click(function() {
        // create a form, and add rotation as an element
        var newForm = $('<form>', {
            'action': 'yourPHPcode.php', // don't know the name of your php code, so used yourPHPcode.php
            'method': 'post'
        }).append($('<input>', {
            'name': 'rotation',
            'value': rotation,
            'type': 'hidden'
        }));
        // add the form to the page, and submit it
        newForm.appendTo('body').submit();
    });
});
```

then in your php code (don't know the name of your php code, so used `yourPHPcode.php`)

```
<?php 
session_start(); 

$src = $_SESSION['picture'];

if($_SESSION['format'] == "image/png")
{
    $img_r =  imagecreatefrompng($src); 
} 
else if($_SESSION['format'] == "image/gif")
{
    $img_r =  imagecreatefromgif($src); 
} 
else if($_SESSION['format'] == "image/jpeg")
{
    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src); 
}

if(isset($_POST['rotation'])
{
    $img_r = imagerotate($img_r, $_POST['rotation'], 0);
}


if($_SESSION['format'] == "image/png")
{
    imagepng($img_r, 'upload/' . basename($src));
} 
else if($_SESSION['format'] == "image/gif")
{
    imagegif($img_r, 'upload/' . basename($src));
} 
else if($_SESSION['format'] == "image/jpeg")
{
    imagejpeg($img_r, 'upload/' . basename($src));
} 

header('Location: picture.php');
?>
```

**edit**
As php's `imagerotate()` rotates `anticlockwise`, you will need to convert `rotation` to a php friendly rotation. In `$("#save").click(function() {` you can create a `var rotationPHP` that you will send to php

```
$(function() {                                 
    var rotation = 0;                            
    $("#left").click(function() {
        rotation = (rotation -90) % 360; 
        $("#spin-pic").rotate(rotation);
    });
    $("#right").click(function() {
        rotation = (rotation + 90) % 360;
        $("#spin-pic").rotate(rotation);
    });
    $("#save").click(function() {
        // create a php friendly rotation value
        // left -90 & right 270 == php 90, left -180 & right 180 == php 180, left -270 & right 90 == php 270
        var rotationPHP = (rotation == -90 || rotation == 270) ? 90 : (rotation == -180 || rotation == 180) ? 180 : (rotation == -270 || 90) ? 270: 0;

        // create a form, and add rotation as an element
        var newForm = $('<form>', {
            'action': 'yourPHPcode.php', // don't know the name of your php code, so used yourPHPcode.php
            'method': 'post'
        }).append($('<input>', {
            'name': 'rotation',
            'value': rotationPHP,
            'type': 'hidden'
        }));
        // add the form to the page, and submit it
        newForm.appendTo('body').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: .It works, but the the rotated image rotates the opposite way... e.g; If I rotate the image left, it is saved as right... But the next I rotate it where I want, it's saved as normal. Please help

Comment: looking at the docs for [`imagerotate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php) -> `resource imagerotate ( resource $image , float $angle , int $bgd_color [, int $ignore_transparent = 0 ] )` and `angle: Rotation angle, in degrees. The rotation angle is interpreted as the number of degrees to rotate the image anticlockwise.`. So php `imagerotate()` goes `anticlockwise`, where it looks like jqueryrotate's `..rotate()` is `clockwise`. So you will need to calculate the difference from 360.

Comment: And how do you do that?

Comment: Basically, I've changed this $("#right").click(function() {
        rotation = (rotation - 90) % 360;
        $("#spin-pic").rotate(rotation);
    }); 
It's weird, because this should turn the picture left , but it turn right!!!

Comment: I have updated my answer. On save you need to change your javascript `rotation` to a php `rotation`. I did this with `var rotationPHP` using a ternary operation.

Comment: For a very strange reason it works without your update... 
I have changed - to + and + to - ... So when I say to turn left it turns right!!! How is this possible!!! ???

Comment: I don't know how to thank you!! I have used your update and the black bars disappeared! Thanks a lot! Best luck to you and to your family!

Comment: By the way look at the second box of my php code... and scroll down